# How can I run artisan Command to work In background laravel

Tags: laravel

I want to run the `php artisan schedule:work` command but the issue is that when i close putty it terminate the operation while i need it to remain processing on server

my server is running Ubuntu 20.4.1 LTS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, the command `schedule:work` is for local development environment.
While you want to run your scheduler on server you should add a cron job like the following:

First, Go to your terminal, ssh into your server, cd into your project and run this command:

```
crontab -e
```

This will open the server Crontab file, paste the code below into the file, save and then exit.

```
* * * * * cd /path-to-your-project && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Here we added one Cron job which executes every minute to start the Laravel scheduler.

Don't forget to replace `/path-to-your-project`  with your project path.

Comment: Does the Number of Starts matter?

Comment: of course, * * * * * means every minute of every hour of every day of every month and every day of the week.

Comment: check this link https://serverfault.com/a/601660 would help to understand what each star means

Comment: I lost the Connection to the Database after instaling this crontab

Answer (score 0):

Use "nohup php artisan schedule:work"

Answer (score 0):

Go to your project path e.g. `cd /var/www/mywebsite`

Command this

```
crontab -e
```

choose editor `nano number 1` if it shows a list of editors.

below of file add this.

```
* * * * * php /var/www/mywebsite/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

save it `CTR+S`